# what is the path to a drawable image so i can insert in to a file

Tags: android

After failing to insert a sdcard image in to a file, I want to try and insert a drawable image in to a file, anyone know the path to a drawable image? Thx

Comment: can you explain the question in detail

Comment: File file = new File(path of drawable goes here);

Comment: You want to include an image in file?

Comment: its `R.Drawable.icon` for getting image from **drawable folder**

Answer (score 0):

Make an object of "Bitmap" from the drawble as:

your drawble -> object of BitmapDrawble - > bitmapDrawble.getBitmap() 
 will convert it into Bitmap.
Now write it into a file by converting it into file output stream and write in a file on your SD Card (its a standard code to accomplish this).